# Isolate SignalR requests

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, signalr

I am trying to use signalR as a messaging system for update of progress bars etc on a web page - and I need to be able to isolate the progess ( or whatever message ) to a specific page.

```
IHubContext hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<InventoryHub>();
```

Messages like>> `hubContext.Clients.All.InitialiseProgress(inventoryData.Count());`

Obviously the problem is `Clients.All` - I am just not sure how I wire it up so that when it sends back from the server to client - it only sends to the page it was called from. I can't get my head around the `connectionid`.

Please help :-)

Comment: "I am just not sure how I wire it up so that when it sends back from the server to client - it only sends to the page it was called from" - I assume that means you've come across `Clients.Caller` and that isn't sufficient for your needs?

Comment: Sounds like the right thing - I just can't see how to implement it.
For example I use hubContext.Clients.All.InitialiseProgress(inventoryData.Count());  - but there is no Clients.Caller ....?

Answer (score 0):

You could use SignalR Groups to broadcast progress messages to specific pages.

From [Working with Groups in SignalR](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/working-with-groups):

Adding a connection ID to a group:

```
public class ContosoChatHub : Hub
{
    public Task JoinRoom(string roomName)
    {
        return Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, roomName);
    }

    public Task LeaveRoom(string roomName)
    {
        return Groups.Remove(Context.ConnectionId, roomName);
    }
}
```

Broadcasting to a specific group:

```
Clients.Group(groupName).addChatMessage(name, message);
```

Comment: That's great.. but I would like to use Clients.Caller - I just can't figure out how to instantiate the hub in a way that will let me use it..?

Comment: I just did some testing, and I think `Clients.Caller` isn't available outside of the hub itself, in your case `InventoryHub`. `Groups` is, but if you're really against using groups, you'll have to keep some other kind of lookup of page identifiers to connection IDs.